# How to Importing the large size(10GB) data in one table in mysql database using SSH?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ssh

I have more then 10 GB data in the one table. I want to upload the 10 GB data in only single table.
Is this possible to upload the 10 GB data using the SSH ?
If no then how many maximum data upload in one time in one table using the SSH.

Please...

Thank You.

Comment: SSH/SCP has no size limit to transfers, although your method of importing the data may.

Comment: Why not? What problem did you face, did you try it? Why is this tagged php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upload the database file to your server and import it via the mysql command

e.g.

```
mysql -h HOSTNAME -u USERNAME -p DATABASENAME < file.sql
```

and enter the password when promoted

where...

```
HOSTNAME = localhost/127.0.0.1/etc...
USERNAME = DB User
DATABASENAME = name of the database you are importing into
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the another solutions For **BLUE HOST SERVER**

Using SSH to import your MySQL database

The file must be in .sql format. It can not be compressed in a .zip or .tar.gz file.

1. Upload the SQL file to the server.
2. If the database does not exist please create one with an user. Note the username and password.
3. Log into the server through SSH
4. Navigate to the directory where your .sql file is.

Type this this command:

```
mysql -p -u username database_name < file.sql
```

**OR**

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/162